# Jest serializer double escapes raw HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, snapshot

Whenever Jest serializes raw HTML like

```
<button class="btn">Submit</button>
```

it results in something like this

```
<button class=\\"btn\\">Submit</button>
```

In addition to that Jest doesn't format raw HTML (string) which leads to very hard to read diffs.

The reason why I need this to work properly is because I'm using enzyme quite and I'm serializing DOM result instead of JSON form of the component which is too long and contains unnecessary information.

Is there a way to configure Jest serializer so that it identifies strings that are HTML and formats them properly?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/jest-serializer-html?

Comment: That's awesome it does exactly what I need! Thanks